# Will using F-strings to request data cause SQL injections?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, sql-injection

I'm unfamiliar with how injection attacks work. Will using f-strings in .execute() make me vulnerable to injection, if I only request data (not update/insert)?

Similarly, let's say I'm trying to edit a column. How can I put in my own variables through .execute() without an f-string?

i.e.

```
new_date = '30/10/2022'

my_database.execute(f'UPDATE people SET birthday={new_date} WHERE name="Odin"')
```

What would be the best way to update the data?

Also, how do I tell if a database has been corrupted?

Edit: I should add my own understanding of 'vulnerability.' The user could input their own SQL commands into new_date so that the execute will input a different command.

Comment: THAT example will not, of course, but if `new_date` came from user input, then of course it could.  Consider if the user entered "1; drop table people;" as the new date.  You must let the database connector do it: `my_database.execute('UPDATE people SET birthday=? WHERE name="Odin"', (new_date,))`.

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: you could put some sort of validation around the date.  For example if you know it's meant to be in some sort of a range (ie this year)

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you. I'm guessing that code make the connector not consider new_date as a command? So even if I put in an SQL command it would just insert "1; drop table people;" as my birthday and not execute it?

Comment: Obligatory XKCD [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) reference.

Comment: The database connector will add the escapes that are necessary to make that whole thing a simple string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will leave you vulnerable, **only if `new_date` can be changed by users**. For example, let's say `new_date` is set to `30/10/2022; DROP DATABASE users --` by a user. The f-string will then resolve to

```
UPDATE people SET birthday=30/10/2022; DROP DATABASE users -- WHERE name="Odin"
```

If this query is sent to your database, then it will delete a database named `users`.

To make user input safe to be sent to a database, you must sanitize it. To sanitize your database input, see [this web page](https://bobby-tables.com/python.html). For example, code is safe:

```
my_database.execute('UPDATE people SET birthday=%s WHERE name="Odin"', (new_date,))
```

If `new_date` is constant and cannot be changed in any way by the user, it is *theoretically* safe. However, always err on the side of caution. Personally, I choose to sanitize all input and not risk it.

Comment: Note that you need a comma after `new_date` to make it a tuple.

Comment: @TimRoberts Good call, I've updated my answer.